# PHP SQLite3 Insert and select last ID not returning result

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to insert new data to SQLite db and select the last ID, when I'm executing the statement in SQLite browser I see that the statement is correct and I get the result. 
But when I'm trying to get the result in my PHP script, I get "null".

```
<?php

class SQLiteDb extends SQLite3{

    function __construct(){
        $this->open('chat.db');
        $this->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
                        `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                        `username`  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                        `status`    VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
                        `date_created`  VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
                    )');
    }
}


$conn = new SQLiteDb();

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, status, date_created) VALUES ('test','active','23/09/2015 14:44'); SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS last_id;"


$lastId = $conn->querySingle($sql); 
var_dump($lastId);//returns null


$lastId = $conn->query($sql); 
var_dump($lastId); //returns object(SQLite3Result)[3]
var_dump($lastId->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)); //returns false
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: maybe useful? [SQLiteDatabase::lastInsertRowid — Returns the rowid of the most recently inserted row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-last-insert-rowid.php)

Comment: - SQLite returned no errors

- Ryan, I saw that link before but unfortunately I did not understand how to use that method correctly

Comment: `$lastInsertId = $conn->lastInsertRowid();` does what you expect. It has been tested with your code.

Answer (score 0):

To execute multiple SQL statements, you would have to call `querySingle()` or `query()` multiple times.

Anyway, the easiest way to get the last inserted `rowid` is to call `$conn->lastInsertRowid()`.